# Drop listener for each character within a string?

Tags: java, android

I am making a cross word game. So far, I have a few text views within the main activity. At the moment, it compares the first character of each string and if they match it's a valid placement.

```
if(dropTarget.getText().toString().charAt(0) == dropped.getText().toString().charAt(0))
```

So what I am wondering is how would check to see if a user hovered over any character of a word, how would I retrieve the index of that character that the user is hovering over? Would I set a drop listener on the characters of the string? (Sounds odd I know.) Is there a better way? Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
     //actions
}
```

The mouse event mouseEntered will recognize things that the mouse is hovering over.

Comment: will that work for touch tho? I mean obviously you have a mouse that hovers on a desktop and clicks the object you want, but with phone you have just a touch or click the object you want but with no hover. (If that makes any sense)